# Mongodb query by array field and show queried items in result

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have a student collection, wanna get students who have **lessonA**, **lessonB**.
 
for example student collection, (Lessons array field is not embeded, its releational, i have lessons collection)

```
{ name : 'studentX', lessons : [lessonA, lessonB, lessonF]}
{ name : 'studentY', lessons : [lessonC, lessonD, lessonE]}
{ name : 'studentZ', lessons : [lessonE, lessonF]}
{ name : 'studentT', lessons : [lessonA, lessonG, lessonH]}
```

When i try that query `db.students.find(lessons: { $in : [lessonA, lessonB] })`, it returns

```
 { name : 'studentX', lessons : [lessonA, lessonB, lessonF]}
 { name : 'studentT', lessons : [lessonA, lessonG, lessonH]}
```

but, dont want to get other lessons in lessons array field, infact all i want is;

```
 { name : 'studentX', lessons : [lessonA, lessonB]}
 { name : 'studentT', lessons : [lessonA]}
```

I tried projection queries, but couldn't, how can i get that result ?

Comment: Accidentally posted half an answer while still typing. See the **full** answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator in projection coupled with "matching" the element you want in find:

```js
db.collection.find({ "lessons": "lessonA" }, { "lessons.$" })
```

or if you want to do it another way:

```js
db.collection.find({ }, { "lessons": { "$elemMatch": "lessonA" }})
```

In order to not reqstrict the documents returned, but restrict the content of the array in projection. Also see [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/).

But what you **cannot** do is project like this with **more than one** element. Not using the positional type of matching anyway. For that use [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Filter first to reduce the matching documents
    { "$match": { "lessons": { "$in": [ "lessonA", "lessonB" ] },

    // Unwind the array
    { "$unwind": "$lessons" },

    // Actually filter the array elements
    { "$match": { "lessons": { "$in": [ "lessonA", "lessonB" ] },

    // Group back to array form
    { "$group": { 
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": { "$first": "$name" },
        "lessons": { "$push": "$lessons" }
    }}
])
```

And that works as [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) can [$unwind](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array as separate documents, then "filter" with [$match](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) and then finally [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) and return the altered document.

Comment: good and enough explanation, it works correctly thanks Neil ;)